# Noch vs Mehr - when to use the other?

Tags: word-choice

If I were to ask something like "Can I have one more apple", I would *apparently* say

> Kann ich noch einen Apfel?

Using **noch.**

If I were to ask something like "Can I have more apples?" (Only taking out the word "**one**" and making "apple" singular) I would *apparently* say:

> Kann ich mehr Äpfel?

How am I to know when to use **mehr** over **noch**? Do I only use *noch* when talking about a singular object? Do I only use *mehr* when talking about plural objects?

Comment: I don't like "Kann ich noch einen Apfel?" I'd say "Kann ich mir noch einen Apfel nehmen? Kann ich noch einen Apfel essen? Kann ich noch einen Apfel haben?"

Comment: Not using _haben_ in your example is considered bad style. Small children usually get corrected for omitting it. That said, while you can use _noch_ in either example (Can ich noch Äpfel haben?), _mehr_ should normally only be used in case of uncountable / plural objects and can also be combined with _noch_ (Kann ich noch mehr Wasser haben? Heute gibt es mehr Schnee als gestern). It does work with simple plurals as well (Kann ich mehr Knödel haben?), although I'd consider it definitely less elegant.

Comment: @Ingmar: Je kleiner das Obst und je häufiger man mehrere davon nimmt ... - "kann ich noch mehr Erdbeeren/Kirschen haben?". Bei einer Verpflegung für eine längere Tour, bei der es durchaus üblich wäre mehrere Äpfel mitzunehmen wäre eine solche Formulierung für Äpfel aber auch ganz natürlich.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a commenter, I don´t like the sentences at all. Literally,

> Kann ich noch einen Apfel?

would mean something like

> Can I another apple?  (no "have" etc. here)

People will understand that you want to have another one, but still...
Append a essen/haben/nehmen/kaufen/... (eat/have/take/buy), whatever you want to do. And even better than

> Kann ich noch einen Apfel nehmen? <=> Can I take another apple?

would be

> Darf ich noch einen Apfel nehmen? <=> May I take take another apple?

It´s nitpicking, but you don´t need t ask the other person if you are *able* to take it.

About noch, einen and mehr: Let´s start with a simple

> Darf ich *einen* Apfel nehmen?
>   May I take *a* apple?
>   (or)
>   May I take *one* apple?

Ok when you´re asking for the first apple, strange if you have already one.

> Darf ich *noch einen* Apfel nehmen?
>   May I take *another* apple?

You have already one or more apples, but you still want another one.
From another angle: Repeated "one". Asking multiple times with *einen* would imply that you´ve forgotten the apples you already have, so starting with the second question, add a *noch*
(and don´t ask 10 times for a single apple)

> Darf ich *mehrere* Äpfel nehmen? (attention, plural **Ä**)
>   May I take *multiple* apples?

You currently have no apples and want an unspecified amount (at least two, else use *einen*).
Instead of *multiple*, you can/should insert an specific amount.

> Darf ich *noch mehr* Äpfel nehmen? (attention, not *noch mehrere*)
>   May I take *even more* apples?

You already have some apples and want more.

> Darf ich *mehr* Äpfel nehmen?
>   May I take *more* apples [than I already took / than you just gave me /
>   than my brother took]?

Depending on the situation:
a) It´s similar to *noch mehr* (you have already and want more), but not suited for repeated questions (at least starting with the second *mehr*, add a *noch*).
b) You want more than some comparison amount (brothers apples etc.). In this case, it doesn´t matter if you have already some apples or not.